# React re-downloads image after every render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-usememo

Edit:

The reason for re-downloading of resources was related to cacheing of images - I had previously enabled Disable cache in chrome dev tools, disabling it solved the issue!

Comment: You should edit your previous question, instead of asking the same question again [React redownloading the same resource after every render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71602550/react-redownloading-the-same-resource-after-every-render)

Comment: I deleted my previous question, I got an answer here. Thanks for letting me know about the edit option though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't fix this with react, you should rather fix it with caching headers on your images.

For each `<img src="http://your.url" />` the browser **will** perform a network request.

The best way to improve performance is to make sure that request has the proper caching headers, so it's not actually downloading the image each time (rather just once)

Comment: You put me on the right track, I found out that I had previously enabled Disable cache in chrome dev tools and that was the reason for the redownloading of resources... Thanks!